# Delay script every X array item in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, csv, throttling

I need to throttle my API requests. There is a loop within my script that pulls 1000 values from a csv file and loops through each of them, and each value is a separate API call. If I want to, for example, only make 10 API calls a minute...How could I do that? I'm thinking something like this:

```
  csv_array.each_slice(10) do |chunk|
        chunk.each do |x|
          make_api_call(x)
          Delay.one_minute
        end
  end
```

Is there a better option to throttle my API requests, or am I on track with the above thinking? I am using ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: do you want to make 1 api call a minute or 10 in one?

Comment: Is there an underlying purpose for this?

Comment: 10 api calls in one minute. That's just a hypothetical example, the real use case is I am going to be making about 1 million API calls and I just need to throttle the API. Each item in the `csv_array` is going to cause about 10 API calls, so I'm thinking if I can throttle it by csv values then I can just pause the api script for a bit after X number of values. I'm in no hurry for the script to finish, I have just been asked to throttle it. Otherwise I'll just make several small CSV files, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Do you care whether you make ten calls as fast as possible, then sleep for whatever portion of a minute remains, or do you want to make ten calls spaced out over equal intervals in a minute? Are you guaranteed to have the same response time for each request or do you have to measure each request response time and subtract that from the remaining time available?

Comment: The calls do not need to be made as fast as possible - I could spread them out over a minute, or do them in one second and pause for 59 seconds. I'm okay with either. The response time will vary so I would need to subtract it from the remaining time available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used something like this in the past:

```
SLEEP_WINDOW = 60 * 1 # minutes
csv_array.each_slice(10) do |chunk|
  start_time = Time.now
  chunk.each do |x|
    make_api_call(x)
  end
  sleep_time = SLEEP_WINDOW - (Time.now - start_time)
  sleep sleep_time if (sleep_time > 0)
end
```

The assumption is it's OK to blast through the chunks, then any remaining delay time will case the code to sleep. If the API calls took over a minute the code will loop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads to ensure that the correct interval has elapsed before the next call is made. This one spaces out the calls for each member of the csv array:

```
csv_array.each do |x|
  timer = Thread.new { sleep 6 }
  execution = Thread.new { make_api_call(x) }
  [timer, execution].each(&:join)
end
```

The benefit here is that it would ensure a minimum of 6 seconds have elapsed, but if the response happens to take longer than that, the timer will already have expired and the next request can begin right away.